# Push to other view controller while keyboard open

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, keyboard

I have multiple view controllers with a single text field, all I want is keep the keyboard on screen until I reached to the last screen. Currently, I have opened keyboard on `viewWillAppear` but when I navigate to other view keyboard navigate with the screen. I want a keyboard as it is but navigation to be done behind keyboard and courser should focus on next view's `UITextField`.
Right now it's looking like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Added `secondTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewDidLoad()` second VC:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var secondTextField: UITextField!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       secondTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
   }

   ...

}
```

or in `awakeFromNib()` if you work with xib.

Comment: Nop both view controllers are in storyboard.